How to prevent SAP Crystal Reports 2016 from rounding off a large number from SQL Server database source?
I have recently updated the data type of SQL Server database column value from decimal(15,3) to decimal(18,3). Previously this column could support an amount field up to 999999999999.99. Now I need to support value up to 999999999999999.99.
I have an existing crystal report which can display the values up to the older limit which is 999999999999.99, but now, the larger value 999999999999999.99 from the database is getting rounded off to 1000000000000000.00 in the report preview.
I tried using Formula Format as follows to display the number field as text:
ToText({MyNumberField})
Apparently the value is getting rounded off before it could convert to text.
I tried using this code in a Formula Field as well as in Field-->Format Field-->Common-->Display String-->(x-2).
Additionally, I tried using using custom style under the Number section of the Format Editor to edit the 'Rounding' Value, but there is no option to set Rounding to Zero or None.
Using 'Add Command' under the 'Set datasource Location' is not an option for me.
I am using an ODBC Data Source for SQL Server.
Is there any way to prevent this rounding?
I want a number field in the SAP Crystal Report to display the exact value from the database which is 999999999999999.99 and not round it to 1000000000000000.00.

If you have confirmed that it's stored in SQL server correctly, then you can untag SQL server because it's clearly not part of the problem

Did you refresh the fields or whatever it's called these days so CR knows about the new datatype

Yes, I updated the data source. For CR, probably the precision change in data source may not affect it. Apparently CR is not able to handle these large numbers.

Be sure to open the report in Crystal and do: Database, Verify Database...
That should resync the rpt with the data source column properties.

Thank you for the suggestion @MilletSoftware. I have resynced the database multiple times already.

In that case, use an SQL Expression (in Crystal Designer) to cast that number to a string. That would allow you to bypass any precision limitations in Crystal because the conversion would occur on the DBMS side.

I am working on an existing report with many columns. As mentioned in the details, using SQL expression is not an option for me. Is there a way to handle this round off issue with SQL Sever ODBC connection using a Formula field or Format Edtitor?

According to this SAP document: https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1204707
Up to, and including Crystal 2016: "Numbers / Doubles are both real floating-point number types, and are susceptible to roundoff errors... Crystal Reports is capable of having 15th significant digits of decimal precision ..."
So SQL Expressions seems to be the way to go.
